# Tkinter not updating labels properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, label

This is the code:

```
for row in results:
    ColumnCounter += 1
    id_list.append(row['ID'])
    #print(id_list)  # DEBUG
    tk.Label(DisplayWindow, text=str(RowCounter - 1), fg="black", font="none 8 bold").grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    ColumnCounter += 1
    firstname_list.append(row['FIRST_NAME'])
    #print(firstname_list)  # DEBUG
    tk.Label(DisplayWindow, text=firstname_list[ListCounter], fg="black", font="none 8 bold").grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    ColumnCounter += 1
    surname_list.append(row['SURNAME'])
    #print(surname_list)  # DEBUG
    tk.Label(DisplayWindow, text=surname_list[ListCounter], fg="black", font="none 8 bold").grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    ColumnCounter += 1
    username_list.append(row['USERNAME'])
    #print(username_list)  # DEBUG
    tk.Label(DisplayWindow, text=username_list[ListCounter], fg="black", font="none 8 bold").grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    ColumnCounter += 1
    email_list.append(row['EMAIL'])
    #print(email_list)  # DEBUG
    tk.Label(DisplayWindow, text=email_list[ListCounter], fg="black", font="none 8 bold").grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter, sticky=W)
    tk.Button(DisplayWindow, text="Select Row", command=lambda CurrentValue=row: [SelectRow(CurrentValue['ID'], CurrentValue['FIRST_NAME'], CurrentValue['SURNAME'], CurrentValue['USERNAME'], CurrentValue['EMAIL']), DisplayWindow.destroy()]).grid(row=RowCounter, column=ColumnCounter + 1, sticky=E)

    RowCounter += 1
    ColumnCounter = -1
    ListCounter += 1
```

Everytime this for loop get re-ran, the labels do not update their texts properly. It's displaying half stuff from the old text and half stuff from the new text. I've tried replacing the text with `textvariable=SomeStringVariable_Name` (`StringVar`) in all labels but again, same problem. How can I fix this?

(The variable results is a dictionary. To be more precise, it's a fetchall from a MySQL database.)

Comment: You're not updating anything. You just create new widgets on top of the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlapping issue can be resolved by assigning a background color to the `label`, and adjusting the `"sticky=W"` option to `"sticky=W+E"`.

That way, the new background will (stretch over and) completely cover the old text.

That is (I believe) a possible solution you may have been after. The following is a bit of advice on label management, to gain some more control over the labels.

If the information in the labels themselves are not updating:

Assign each label to a variable. Then, each time the loop is ran, update the information using `widget.configure(option=value)`

```
label_id_list.configure(text=str(RowCounter - 1))
label_firstname_list.configure(text=firstname_list[ListCounter])
label_surname_list.configure(text=surname_list[ListCounter])
label_username_list.configure(text=username_list[ListCounter])
label_email_list.configure(text=email_list[ListCounter])
button_email_list.configure(command=lambda CurrentValue=row: [SelectRow(CurrentValue['ID'], CurrentValue['FIRST_NAME'], CurrentValue['SURNAME'], CurrentValue['USERNAME'], CurrentValue['EMAIL']))
```

The label information will update; no need to call `widget.grid()`